# Is there a clipboard manager with Paste All functionality?

Tags: clipboard-manager

Does any of the linux clipboard managers have the feature **paste all**?
A simple scenario:
1. Copy first piece of text.
2. Copy second piece of text.
3. Copy n-th piece of text.
4. Command the clipboard manager to paste all of the copied text pieces.

The same ability for images or a combination of text and images would be useful as well but let's simplify to text only case. 
I tried few of the recommended applications and haven't found this in neither of them. 
P.S. I use Ubuntu 11.10, so gnome programs are preferred.

Comment: similar question to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96181/how-do-i-copy-the-whole-history-of-the-clipboard-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Parcellite has this capability.

http://parcellite.sourceforge.net (instructions for whitlisting parcellite on Unity)
https://sourceforge.net/projects/parcellite/files/parcellite/parcellite-1.1.1

If you want the appindicator version for unity,
https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/ppa

Comment: TBH I'm shocked such obvious function is so hard to find. I'll check it out.