# Export Qlipper clipboard history in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, clipboard

*Is there a way to export all clipboard history items stored in the default Qlipper app in Lubuntu (20.04 LTS)?*

I find the clipboard manager convenient, but would like to export multiple/all items in the history at times. I see some discussion about this of other clipboard managers in [How do I copy the whole history of the clipboard to a text file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96181), but I am interested specifically in the Qlipper app as it comes with Lubuntu.

I couldn't find any options just by clicking the Qlipper icon in the launch bar (which just shows only the history list). There is no "Save As" menu.

Comment: You may have to look at other clipboard managers such as `copyq`. `qlipper` is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Qlipper's clipboard history is stored in ~/.config/Qlipper/qlipper.ini. It's all munged up with a lot of gobbledygook though. Here's some shell that mostly cleans it up:

```
cat ~/.config/Qlipper/qlipper.ini | sed -e 's/\\[0-9xt]*//g' -e 's/plin\(.*\)\/plin/\1/g' | grep 'flipboardContent' | sed 's#^.*flipboardContent/\(.*\);hrs=.*$#\1#g' | sed 's/.http/http/g' | grep -v itemscontent
```